# The view is out of scope when displaying HTML in textview using fromhtml

Tags: android, html, textview

I try to display a piece of HTML in a `textview` while the text is too long. When simply using `Html.fromhtml`, some text is out of scope. I thought adding `<br/>` tag to HTML is not a good way considering the resolution of each device is various. Is there a way to create line breaks automatically? Or, perhaps I could scroll the `textview`?
Any help would be appreciated.